# Create a GUI to add computers to an AD Security Group

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I use Powershell to add computers to my active directory security groups. I was wondering if a GUI could be created that would allow the helpdesk to 1. select the security group from a drop down and 2. to add the computer to the selected group. We use the AD security groups to install software. One is MS Office Install and the other is OpenOffice Install. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I would appreciate any help or advice you may offer.

Comment: Put "Powershell create GUI" into your favorite search engine, do a little research, and come back with specific questions that can be reasonably described as having discrete answers.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your most helpful advice. Thank you for the spell check on my post. Much appreciated. I didn't ask you to create it for me I was asking how to get started. I am new to this. I have been using my favorite search engine and that was how I found this forum. Sorry to have offended you.

Comment: Not offended, just explaining how to get the most out of the site.

Comment: Click in the Help link up toward the upper RH corner of the page, and select "Tour" from the dropdown.  Read through that, expecially the section that sahs "Get answers to practical, detailed questions".  K?

Comment: Thanks again and I will take your advice. Steve

Answer (score 0):

Check out ShowUI, it makes it very easy to design a GUI.
If everything you need will fit on one page then ShowUI is a good choice.
I have used it for two projects with entry fields, pre-populated drop-downs and input validation.

Comment: Thanks Jimbo for the information. I have downloaded a copy and am giving it a shot. I am sorry if I offended anyone with my blatant question for assistance. This is all new to me.